# loop tiling/blocking for large dense matrix multiplication

Tags: c, performance, openmp, sse, matrix-multiplication

I was wondering if someone could show me how to use loop tiling/loop blocking for large dense matrix multiplication effectively.  I am doing ***C = AB*** with 1000x1000 matrices.  I have followed the example on Wikipedia for loop tiling but I get worse results using tiling than without.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_tiling

http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/how-to-use-loop-blocking-to-optimize-memory-use-on-32-bit-intel-architecture

I have provided some code below.  The naive method is very slow due to cache misses.  The transpose method creates the transpose of ***B*** in a buffer.  This method gives the fastest result (matrix multiplication goes as O(n^3) and transpose as O(n^2) so doing the transpose is at least 1000x faster).  The wiki method without blocking is also fast and does not need a buffer.  The blocking method is slower.  Another problem with blocking is it has to update the block several times.  This is a challenge for threading/OpenMP because it can cause race conditions if one is not careful.

I should point out that using AVX with a modification of the transpose method I get results faster than Eigen.  However, my results with SSE are a bit slower than Eigen so I think I could use caching better.

Edit:
I think I have an idea what I want to do.  It comes from Cannon's algorithm from 1969.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_multiplication#Communication-avoiding_and_distributed_algorithms

I need to do block matrix multiplication and have each thread handle a sub-matrix of ***C*** rather than ***A*** and ***B***.  For example if I divide my matrices into four blocks.  I would do:

```
+-+      +-+     +-+      +-+   +-+      +-+
|          |     |          |   |          |
| C1    C2 |     | A1    A2 |   | B1    B2 |
|          |  =  |          | x |          |
| C3    C4 |     | A3    A4 |   | B3    B4 |
|          |     |          |   |          |
+-+      +-+     +-+      +-+   +-+      +-+


thread 1: C1 = A1B1 + A2B3
thread 2: C2 = A1B2 + A2B4
thread 3: C3 = A3B1 + A4B3
thread 4: C4 = A3B2 + A4B4
```

That removes the race condition.  I'll have to think about this.

```
void matrix_mult_naive(const float*A , const float* B, float* C, const int N, const int M, const int K) {
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            float tmp = 0;
            for(int l=0; l<M; l++) {
                tmp += A[M*i+l]*B[K*l+j];
            }
            C[K*i + j] = tmp;
        }
    }
}
void matrix_mult_transpose(const float*A , const float* B, float* C, const int N, const int M, const int K) {
    float *B2 = (float*)aligned_malloc(M*K*sizeof(float), 32);
    transpose(B, B2, M, K, 1);
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            float tmp = 0;
            for(int l=0; l<M; l++) {
                tmp += A[M*i+l]*B2[M*j+l];
            }
            C[K*i + j] = tmp;
        }
    }
    aligned_free(B2);
}

void matrix_mult_wiki(const float*A , const float* B, float* C, const int N, const int M, const int K) {
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            C[K*i + j] = 0;
        }  
    }
    #pragma omp parallel for
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int l=0; l<M; l++) {
            float a  = A[M*i+l];
            for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
                C[K*i + j] += a*B[K*l+j];
            }
        }
    }
}

void matrix_mult_wiki_block(const float*A , const float* B, float* C, const int N, const int M, const int K) {
   const int block_size = 8;  //I have tried several different block sizes
   for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
       for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
           C[K*i + j] = 0;
       }
    }
    for(int l2=0; l2<M; l2+=block_size) {
        for(int j2=0; j2<K; j2+=block_size) {
        #pragma omp parallel for
            for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
                for(int l=l2; l<min(M, l2+block_size); l++) {
                    for(int j=j2; j<min(K, j2+block_size); j++) {
                        C[K*i + j] += A[M*i+l]*B[K*l+j];
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You want the parallel for to go around the outer (tile) loops, not within them.   The idea is for each core to be able to do its tile multiplication in fast local cache, and for several cores to be able to do that at the same time.

Comment: That creates a race condition.  C[K*i +j] is being written to several times.

Comment: I mean for for example that for i=0, j=0 C[0] is written to multiple times in the block method.

Comment: Have you tried a different loop permutation? For matrix multiplication without tiling, lij order leads to fewer cache misses compared to ijl order that you are using.

Comment: Have you tried row skipping? If you have t threads and nxn matrix, each thread i where 0 <= i < t starts by computing the ith row then skip to row t+i, then 2t+i etc until mt+i >= n for some m. If you have many cores on your cpu, this will be fast

Answer (score 8):

The best results I've gotten are by adding one more `for` loop that blocks over your `N`, and by rearranging the loops. I also hoisted loop-invariant code, but the compiler's optimizer should hopefully do this automatically. The block size should be the cache line size divided by `sizeof(float)`. This got it ~50% faster than the transposed approach.

If you have to pick just one of AVX or blocking, using AVX extensions (`vfmadd###ps` and `haddps`) is still substantially faster. Using both is best and straightforward to add given that you're already testing if the block size is a multiple of `64 / sizeof(float)` == 16 floats == two 256-bit AVX registers.

- Transposed: 1,816,522 ticks
- Tiling: 892,431 (51% faster)
- AVX+tiling: 230,512 (87% faster)

Tiling:

```
void matrix_mult_wiki_block(const float*A , const float* B, float* C,
                            const int N, const int M, const int K) {
    const int block_size = 64 / sizeof(float); // 64 = common cache line size
    for(int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for(int j=0; j<K; j++) {
            C[K*i + j] = 0;
        }
    }
    for (int i0 = 0; i0 < N; i0 += block_size) {
        int imax = i0 + block_size > N ? N : i0 + block_size;

        for (int j0 = 0; j0 < M; j0 += block_size) {
            int jmax = j0 + block_size > M ? M : j0 + block_size;

            for (int k0 = 0; k0 < K; k0 += block_size) {
                int kmax = k0 + block_size > K ? K : k0 + block_size;

                for (int j1 = j0; j1 < jmax; ++j1) {
                    int sj = M * j1;

                    for (int i1 = i0; i1 < imax; ++i1) {
                        int mi = M * i1;
                        int ki = K * i1;
                        int kij = ki + j1;

                        for (int k1 = k0; k1 < kmax; ++k1) {
                            C[kij] += A[mi + k1] * B[sj + k1];
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

---

As for the Cannon reference, the [SUMMA algorithm](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/lawnspdf/lawn96.pdf) is a better one to follow.

---

In case anyone else is optimizing tall-skinny multiplications ({~1e9 x 50} x {50 x 50}, how I ended up here), the transposed approach is nearly identical in performance to the blocked approach up to *n*=18 (floats). *n*=18 is a pathological case (way worse than 17 or 19) and I don't quite see the cache access patterns that cause this. All larger *n* are improved with the blocked approach.

Comment: Could you please explain why the for loop "for (int j0 = 0; j0 < M; j0 += block_size) " j0 needs to < N but not K?

Comment: @Americancurl It is because `k` and not `j` iterates over the columns in matrix `C`.